# Am I allowed to know spells I can't cast yet?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

As a sorcerer, am I allowed to know spells I don't have the spells slots for yet? Reason being, I don't want any more lower level spells and would prefer to have more later game spells.

Comment: Could you clarify: do you ask about knowing, say, any level 4 spell before level 7, thus, having only level 1-2-3 spell slots? Or about knowing **two** level 4 spells while having only **one** level 4 slot?

Comment: It says in the first line i wanted to know if i could cast spells i don't have spells for yet? i am unsure what is unclear about it, its been answer anyway.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, you can only learn spells of a level that you have spell slots for. From the Sorcerer's Spells Known feature:

> The
>   Spells
>   Known
>   column
>   of
>   the
>   Sorcerer
>   table
>   shows
>   when
>   you
>   learn
>   more
>   sorcerer
>   spells
>   of
>   your
>   choice.
>   **Each
>   of
>   these
>   spells
>   must
>   be
>   of
>   a
>   level
>   for
>   which
>   you
>   have
>   spell
>   slots.**
>   For
>   instance,
>   when
>   you
>   reach
>   3rd
>   level
>   in
>   this
>   class,
>   you
>   can
>   learn
>   one
>   new
>   spell
>   of
>   1st
>   or
>   2nd
>   level.

However, you've said that your goal here is to stop learning low-level spells so that, later on when you can actually use them, you can have more high-level spells. Fortunately, there is a solution to this problem baked into the class.

> Additionally,
>   when
>   you
>   gain
>   a
>   level
>   in
>   this
>   class,
>   you
>   can
>   choose
>   one
>   of
>   the
>   sorcerer
>   spells
>   you
>   know
>   and
>   replace
>   it
>   with
>   another
>   spell
>   from
>   the
>   sorcerer
>   spell
>   list,
>   which
>   also
>   must
>   be
>   of
>   a
>   level
>   for
>   which
>   you
>   have
>   spell
>   slots.

So, right now, you have to learn spells you can cast. However, as you gain levels, you can dump low-level spells in favour of higher-level spells. In this way, you can keep your stock of spells known relevant to you as you level. It also means you can try out spells you're not sure about and get rid of them if you don't like them.

Comment: Is the spell swap limited to one spell per level gain?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yep, exactly